# Relative times in timeline card

Tags: google-mirror-api

Is there a way to show relative times (e.g. "in 4 min) in the html of a timeline card? Given the latency involved with delivering cards I can't be certain the time will be correct if I hardcode it in the html, and I'd also prefer not to have to update the card every minute (updating as the time passes is fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no specific way to do this. JavaScript that might be embedded in cards will not run, and there is no way to have an application attached to the timeline run using the Mirror API.

If you have a specific, general, feature request that you think can be backed by a general use case, you may wish to submit it on the issue page at https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/

Comment: "specific general"... sheesh, who writes like that? Oh... me. What I was trying to say is that if you can identify specific uses for the feature, but can generalize it so it may be useful to more people than just you, it might be a good issue to submit.